# How could I convert from IP address to MAC address

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I want to store all the MAC the mac address which has access to my server. 
All I know are only the IP addresses. All the machines are under unique gateway. 
Could I got the MAC address from their IP address?

Comment: If the server is also the DHCP server and all connected machines are getting their IP-addresses from that server, then you can. Or if you can access the dhcp server logs. This works in a LAN. If there are several routers in between its impossible.

Comment: I think this question doesn't deserve down-votes, it's a well-formed question however the answer is simply _NO_ in general. Although, I agree it should be closed as Duplicated or maybe Off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If server and client are on the same network, you will have to use [ARP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). This protocol is designed to get the MAC address to a given IP address.

As soon as there is something like a router between client and server, ARP will only reveal the MAC address of the router since this is the target for your ethernet packets.

Answer (score 7):

MAC addresses are not part of any protocol that gets routed, you will never get the MAC address of a machine that is on the other side of a router or switch.

They are are the addresses of the physical ports, not of machines (which are what you're taling to using IP).

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is, no You Cannot get MAC Address from an IP Address for clients connecting to your server unless both the machines are on same Physical network

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get MAC address from IP address. MAC address is a physical address of network device, and IP address is not.

IP address is not bound to one device in general.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-mac-and-ip-address/)

the post says

```
   An IP address is usually assigned by the network administrator or internet 
service provider, you are either provided a static one at the beginning or 
given a dynamic one every time you connect to the network. 
      This is not true with MAC addresses as it is already embedded on the device 
or the network card during manufacturing. It is supposed to be permanent and could 
 not be changed by anyone as it was meant to identify a specific network interface 
card no matter where it is in the world.
```

There are however ways to change mac addess, but i don't think it is possible to get mac address using IP- Address

Comment: The final sentence of the quotation is incorrect. Most NICs support changing the MAC address from e.g. the control panel. Many organisations do this on the basis of logical or physical location so they can track the asset.